# When reading cookie in CGI program, only the first line is retrieved

Tags: c, cgi

I have this problem.
I write a CGI code, which deals with multiline TEXTAREA elements. When
I read POST request variables, all the lines are retrieved. But when I write multiline value to cookie and then read it back, I get only the first line. What should I do about it?

```C
void
write_ to_cookie(char *name,
        char *value,
        char *expires,
        char *path,
        char *domain,
        int secure) {
    printf("Set-Cookie: %s=%s;", name, value);
    if (expires) {
        printf(" EXPIRES=%s;", expires);
    }
    if (path) {
        printf(" PATH=%s;", path);
    }
    if (domain) {
        printf(" DOMAIN=%s;", domain);
    }
    if (secure) {
        printf(" SECURE");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

To read cookies and requests I use the same function, based on `strtok`. It works well when dealing with POST requests, but with Cookie it sees only the first line

```
static LIST *lparse(char *str, char *sep){
    //str is 'req1=val1;req2=val2', sep is ';'
    if (!str || !sep) {
        return NULL;
    }
    LIST *cp = NULL;
    char *bfr = sdupl(str);
    char *tok = strtok(bfr, sep);
    while (tok) {
        cp = ladd(cp, sextrkey(tok), sextrval(tok));
        tok = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }
    return cp;
}
```

Comment: My code is a bit disorganized and fragmented so it's hard to show it.

Comment: Where's the code to read it back?

Comment: You should edit the answer and put it there and delete that last comment so newcomers to the question can see it all and improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie values must be URL encoded. That means you have to replace characters like `;` and `\n` with their hex equivalents (which are `%3B` and `%0A` for the examples I gave).

Here's a simple C function for printing a URL-encoded string:

```
#include <string.h>
void print_url_encoded(char *s) {
    int c;
    while ((c=*s) != '\0') {
        if (c<33 || c>126 || strchr("!\"*%'();:@&=+$,/?#[]",*s)) {
            printf("%%%02X",c & 0xff);
        }
        else {
            putchar(c);
        }
        s++;
    }
}
```

Then, instead of

```
printf("Set-Cookie: %s=%s;", name, value);
```

use this code:

```
printf("Set-Cookie: %s=", name);
print_url_encoded(value);
putchar(';');
```

You'll also need a URL decode routine to process the cookie values sent back from the client.